# Replace Turn Off/Shut down with Hibernate

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I've seen laptops which have Hibernate at the Start menu instead of Shut down, and I find it very useful. How do I enable it at my desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do both on any computer. If you press the little right arrow next to 'Shut Down' it will give you a list of other options.

If you want to change it so that the default action is Hibernate as opposed to Shut Down, then;

Right click the start button, click 'Properties' and change 'Power Button Action' to whatever you want it to do.

[image]

Hope that helps.